# Do we have the following inequality $\operatorname{Var}(X\mid X\in A) \le \operatorname{Var}(X)$?

Tags: probability-theory, variance

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Let $X$ be some random veriable. Is the following inequality true
$$
\Var(X\mid X\in A) \le \Var(X)
$$
where $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is some measurable set.  The conditional variance is defined as
$$
E[(X-E[X\mid X\in A])^2\mid X\in A]  = \Var(X\mid X\in A). 
$$

For expected value it is easy to find a counter example. For example, take $X = \pm 1$ equally likely. Then,
\begin{align}
& E[X]=0 \\
& E[X\mid X \in (0,2)]=1
\end{align}

If we do this for variance, we get that
\begin{align}
E[(X-E[X\mid X\in A])^2\mid X\in A]= 0
\end{align}

This inequality appears to be true for the case when $X$ is normal with variance $\sigma$ and $A$ is an interval.
We have that
$$
\Var(X\mid X\in [-t,t])= \sigma^2 \rho(t)
$$
where $\rho(t) \le 1$. See [wiki][1] for more details

I tried to show this but only got to the following inequality
\begin{align}
\Var(X\mid X\in A)&= E[(X-E[X\mid X\in A])^2\mid X\in A]\\
& \le E[(X-E[X])^2\mid X\in A] \text{ use $E[X\mid X\in A]$ is minimizer of quadratic term} \\
& = \frac{E[(X-E[X])^2 1_{A}(X)]}{P(X\in A)}\\
& \le \frac{E[(X-E[X])^2 ]}{P(X\in A)}\\
& = \frac{\Var(X)}{P(X\in A)}\\
\end{align}
[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: This doesn't seem like it needs to be true. What if $X$ is a random variable that is constant on $A^c$ but has high variance inside $A$?

Comment: @rubikscube09 Yes, I was trying to construct such an example, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: The answer below me seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @rubikscube09 : I wonder if you meant the DENSITY is constant on $A^c$? But that doesn't mean $\operatorname{var}(X\mid X\in A^c)=0. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think we're mincing words here (or I am being too imprecise) - all I meant was a random variable whose support is say ${0} \cup [1/4,3/4]$  with $P(X = 0) = 1/2$, and $P(X \in [1/4,3/4]) = 1/2)$, with the density of $X$ conditional on it being inside the interval being uniform. The variance conditional on $X$ taking on the value of the point-mass is 0 (because the point mass has positive probability), and the variance of $X$ conditional on it lying in the interval is of course non-zero.

Comment: So if, conditional on $X\in[1/4,3/4],$ it is uniformly distributed in that interval, and otherwise as described in your comment, then $\operatorname{var}(X\mid X\in[1/4,3/4]) = 1/48$ and $\operatorname{var}(X\mid X\notin[1/4,3.4])=0$ and $\operatorname{var}(X) = 7/96,$ so that last is greater then either of the conditional variances, just as the original poster conjectured.

Comment: Well, from my understanding - $\mathrm{Var}(X) = \mathrm{Var}(X | X\in [1/4,3/4]) \mathbb{P}(X \in [1/4,3/4]) + \mathrm{Var}(X | X\not \in [1/4,3/4]) \mathbb{P}(X \not \in [1/4,3/4])  = (1/2)\mathrm{Var}(X | X\not \in [1/4,3/4]) + 0\cdot(1/2) = (1/2)\mathrm{Var}(X | X\not \in [1/4,3/4]) < \mathrm{Var}(X | X\not \in [1/4,3/4])$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample:  $$X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n = 3, p = 1/2),$$ then $$\operatorname{Var}[X] = 3/4,$$ but $$Y = (X \mid X \ne \{1, 2\})$$ is a scaled Bernoulli distribution with scaling constant $3$ and $p = 1/2$, thus $$\operatorname{Var}[Y] = 9(1/2)(1-1/2) = \frac{9}{4}.$$

Comment: With $n=3$ the support of the conditional distribution is $\{0,2,3\}.$ The probabilities are $\Pr(X=0\mid X\ne1) = 1/5, \quad $\Pr(X=2\mid X\ne 1) = 3/5, \quad \Pr(X=3\mid X\ne 1) = 1/5.$ This is not a scaled Bernoulli distribution.

Comment: @MichaelHardy For some reason I was mixing up $n = 2$ and $n = 3$.  I will revise this shortly.

Comment: If $Y\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(3,1/2),$ then $\operatorname{var}(Y) = 9/4$ and $\operatorname{var}(Y\mid Y=3\text{ or } Y=0) = 9/4. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy $Y$ is not itself $\operatorname{Binomial}(n = 3, p = 1/2)$.  $X$ is the binomial variable, and its variance with $n = 3$ and $p = 1/2$ is $np(1-p) = 3/4$.

Comment: If $X\sim\operatorname{Binomial}(4,1/2)$ then $\operatorname{var}(X\mid X\in\{0,4\}) > \operatorname{var}(X).$ So something very similar to what you wrote works. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

I entered some commands into R:

```
y <- qnorm(seq(10000)/10001)
```

This sets $y$ equal to the tuple $\left( \Phi^{-1} \left(\tfrac i {10001}\right) : i = 1,\ldots,1000 \right),$ where $\Phi$ is the cumulative probability distribution of the standard normal distribution.

Then:

```
a <- y[abs(y) > 1]
b <- y[abs(y) < 1]
var(y); var(a); var(b)
```

The output was this:

```
[1] 0.9984691
[1] 2.521473
[1] 0.2912116
```

The first is close to $1,$ as one expects since the variance of the standard normal distribution is $1.$ The second is much bigger.

If one wishes not to conclude that $\operatorname E(Z\mid |Z|>1)> \operatorname E(Z)=1$ on the grounds that what I did is only an approximation, one can still say that a certain discrete distribution that has $10\,000$ possible values, each with probability $1/10\,000,$ satisfies that inequality.

So the proposition is false.